# Send binary data from circuit to PC through USB

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, usb, microchip

I have an 8-bit BUS with a binary word that I want to send to a PC through USB in a certain baud rate. I understand that the cheapest way would be to use a DSP chip, but I'm unfamiliar with microprocessors so I'm looking for a fairly simple way of doing this with some DSP chip that would be fairly easy to implement.

Can you recommend or insight on how can I make this 8-bit word into a DSP chip (which one should I use?) and then made it to the USB port and send it to the PC? From the PC I'll have a C program that is supposed to "catch" that binary number with a certain baud rate - but that I'm able to do.

Thank you very much!

Comment: A DSP is a "digital signal processor", which has little to do with USB. Simplest would be a small microcontroller with enough pins to sample the 8 bits from the bus and a UART and then some RS232 to USB translator chip.

Comment: @Unimportant oh, I see. So, for example, would it be easier if instead of having an 8-bit bus, I'd have a node in my circuit that changes over time between L and H and the UART-to-USB converter and sends the logic value in that node at a certain baud rate?

Comment: If you're going to use an asynchronous serial to USB converter (your "UART-to-USB converter"), **That** would be the side that would need a certain baud rate, and your data would have to be formatted for asynchronous (i.e., proper start and stop bits in between 8 data bits).  On the USB side it's all in USB messages and runs at whatever the bus speed is.  If you have data that's _not_ already formatted for asynchronous serial then you either need one small microcontroller, or a whole bunch of logic chips.

Comment: @TimWescott I can either have the bus with 8 bits from a shift register (all bits in parallel) or have them one by one to be read one after another. Would I always need a microcontroller to interface the L's and H's from the circuit? Can't I just get the L's and H's sequentially in series directly from the circuit node to the module (let's say, PL2303, for example)?

Comment: "Can't I just" -- as I said, no.  But before you ask me _again_ hoping for a different answer, why don't you find a web page on how UARTs work, and see if your proposed solution is compatible with what goes into a UART's receive pin?

Comment: @TimWescott I'm sorry, you are right. My question was if there is another protocol that allows me to do that but I'm assuming there isn't. I will just have to buy both the microcontroller and the uart-usb module. Do you recommend any microchip that is cheap and small (Arduino microcontroller is quite expensive) with +6 pins I/O that could also be programmable?

Comment: @ludicrous In the old ISA bus days (8-bit defined by IBM at first, then later including 16-bit when standardized as ISA), we'd just wire-wrap up (or solder) an ISA board or else buy the parallel port board (or combined parallel + serial board, later) or game port board. You could easily wire up 8 bits in parallel there and just write a PC program to input the data. It was easy. Today, we're screwed. It's PCIe or M2.x or some USB incarnation and life got harder.

Comment: @ludicrous So get yourself something [like this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/EZ430-F2013?qs=3wuez3jz59JrMkK3bemqmA%3D%3D). It's got the USB stuff built into it. It automatically takes advantage of the PC HID drivers that are built into the O/S. Nothing to download needed. You can write simple serial UART code to talk to the on-board USB-gizmo and write standard PC software that thinks it is talking to a UART. (Just a virtual COM port, really.) Then you can just wire your bits into the tiny board there and write a little software on it.

Comment: @ludicrous That unit comes in two board parts: the main board with the CPU and USB communication garbage, and a tiny add-on board. You can buy buckets of those tiny add-on boards, too. And they just come off and on easy-like. So you can destroy a few and be only a few dollars the wiser for it. Or make custom wirings and just plug in the one you need today. There are other "EZ" boards you can get, cheap. And not only from TI. Just look for something like these and wire up to them. I am sure someone always has a parallel-to-USB board you can buy. (But I got the F2013 for $5 each, no ship costs.)

Comment: I’ve had great success with FTDI’s “FIFO to usb” parts: https://ftdichip.com/products/ft245rq/ . They present a buffered serial port in the usb side and are easily attached to any 8 bit bus. There are now apparently 16 bit usb3 versions as well too

Comment: What is your "certain baud rate"? Solutions can be different depending on your rate.

Comment: This? https://ftdichip.com/products/ft245rq/